# Inconsistency with dropdowns displaying values in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm having a problem with my dropdown lists in my child gridview displaying values. For whatever reason the first dropdown in the row works fine and displays the values from the database, the other ones don't display anything.

Below is the code for my gridviews:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GVAccounts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="Horizontal" 
        style="position: relative; margin-top: 10px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="branch" HeaderText="Branch" 
                SortExpression="branch" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="no" HeaderText="Account" 
                SortExpression="account" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") + " " + Eval("surname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="sub" HeaderText="Sub" SortExpression="sub" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalAmount" HeaderText="Hold" 
                SortExpression="TotalAmount" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="loc" HeaderText="LOC" DataFormatString="{0:C}" SortExpression="loc" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="locstatus" HeaderText="LOC status" 
                SortExpression="locstatus" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="HoldCalc" HeaderText="OD/EX Amt" SortExpression="HoldCalc" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="odtimes" HeaderText="#OD" SortExpression="odtimes" />

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>

                    <td colspan="100%">
                        <div id="gridChild" style="display: inline; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">

                        <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                                BorderStyle="Double"  BorderColor="#5D7B9D" Width="80%">

                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />

                            <RowStyle BackColor="#E1E1E1" />

                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />

                            <Columns>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                                            oncheckedchanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" EnableViewState="true" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>  
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="effective" HeaderText="Effective" 
                                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="desc_" HeaderText="Desc" 
                                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="code" HeaderText="TC" 
                                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
                                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="tracer" HeaderText="Cheq #" 
                                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="empl" HeaderText="Empl" 
                                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="balance" HeaderText="OD/EXT Amt" 
                                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownNote" runat="server" 
                                            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownNote_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                            AutoPostBack="True">
                                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>MWC</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>CBM</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Return</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>TSF</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>OK NO S/C</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note1">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddNote2" runat="server" 
                                                onselectedindexchanged="ddNote2_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">NSF</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>Funds Not Clear</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>Post Dated</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>Stale Dated</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>Stop Payment</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>Encoding Incorrect</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddBranch" runat="server" DataSourceID="BranchDataSource" 
                                            DataTextField="branch" DataValueField="branch" AutoPostBack="true">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BranchDataSource" runat="server" 
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ThirdPartyDataConnectionString %>" 
                                            SelectCommand="SELECT [branch] FROM [branch]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextNo" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddType" runat="server" DataSourceID="typeSource" 
                                            DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="Type" AutoPostBack="true">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="typeSource" runat="server" 
                                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ThirdPartyDataConnectionString %>" 
                                            SelectCommand="SELECT [Type] FROM [DMDType]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub">
                                    <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="TextSub" Width="25px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>

                        </div> 
                    </td>

                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="GVFixedHeader" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Below is the method that is having the issue with displaying:

```
Private Function CheckForSubmit() As Boolean
    Try
        conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim cmdNote As New SqlCommand("select note, note1, noteBranch, noteAccountNo, noteType, noteSub, id from DmdOD where id = @id order by effective, time_, seqno_dmddmhi_dmhi", conn)
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select submitted, id, effective FROM DmdOD where no = @no and entered = '" & ddDate.SelectedItem.Text & "' order by effective, time_, seqno_dmddmhi_dmhi", conn)


        Dim objDBId As Object = 0
        Dim id = 0
        Dim objDate As Date
        Dim dateStr As String = ""

        If ddDate.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            cmd = New SqlCommand("select submitted, id, entered FROM DmdOD where no = @no and entered = '" & ddDate.SelectedItem.Text & "' order by effective, time_, seqno_dmddmhi_dmhi", conn)
            '    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("effective", ddDate.SelectedItem.Text))
        Else
            cmd = New SqlCommand("select submitted, id, entered FROM DmdOD where no = @no order by effective, time_, seqno_dmddmhi_dmhi", conn)
        End If
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim i = 0

        For Each row As GridViewRow In GVAccounts.Rows
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@no", row.Cells(1).Text))

            Dim gv As GridView = DirectCast(row.FindControl("gvChildGrid"), GridView)


            conn.Open()

            Dim idReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            'get ids in order
            While (idReader.Read())
                If Not objId.Contains(idReader.GetValue(1)) Then
                    objId.Add(idReader.GetValue(1))
                End If
            End While
            conn.Close()

            conn.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While (reader.Read())
                objSubmit = reader.GetValue(0)
                objDBId = reader.GetValue(1)
                objDate = reader.GetValue(2)
                dateStr = objDate.ToShortDateString
                If dateStr = ddDate.SelectedItem.Text Then
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While

            conn.Close()
            If objSubmit = True And dateStr = ddDate.SelectedItem.Text Then

                For Each r As GridViewRow In gv.Rows

                    cmdNote.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", objId(i)))

                    Dim ddNote As Control = r.FindControl("DropDownNote")
                    Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(ddNote, DropDownList)

                    Dim ddNote2 As Control = r.FindControl("ddNote2")
                    Dim ddlNote As DropDownList = DirectCast(ddNote2, DropDownList)
                    ddlNote.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))

                    Dim ddBranch As Control = r.FindControl("ddBranch")
                    Dim ddBranchBox As DropDownList = DirectCast(ddBranch, DropDownList)
                    ddBranchBox.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))

                    Dim txtAccount As Control = r.FindControl("TextNo")
                    Dim txtAccountBox As TextBox = DirectCast(txtAccount, TextBox)

                    Dim ddType As Control = r.FindControl("ddType")
                    Dim ddTypeBox As DropDownList = DirectCast(ddType, DropDownList)

                    Dim txtSub As Control = r.FindControl("TextSub")
                    Dim txtSubBox As TextBox = DirectCast(txtSub, TextBox)

                    r.Cells(0).Enabled = False
                    r.Cells(8).Enabled = False
                    r.Cells(9).Enabled = False
                    r.Cells(10).Enabled = False
                    r.Cells(11).Enabled = False
                    r.Cells(12).Enabled = False
                    r.Cells(13).Enabled = False

                    'Display fields
                    gv.Columns(8).Visible = True
                    gv.Columns(9).Visible = True
                    gv.Columns(10).Visible = True
                    gv.Columns(11).Visible = True
                    gv.Columns(12).Visible = True
                    gv.Columns(13).Visible = True

                    ddBranchBox.Visible = True
                    txtAccount.Visible = True
                    ddTypeBox.Visible = True
                    txtSub.Visible = True

                    'Get Data for fields
                    conn.Open()
                    cmdNote.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Dim readNotes As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdNote.ExecuteReader()
                    readNotes.Read()
                    'Note
                    If IsDBNull(readNotes.GetValue(0)) Then
                        ddl.SelectedItem.Text = ""
                    Else
                        ddl.SelectedItem.Text = readNotes.GetValue(0)
                    End If
                    'Note1

                    If IsDBNull(readNotes.GetValue(1)) Then
                        'GVAccounts.Columns(12).Visible = False
                        ddlNote.Visible = False
                        ddlNote.SelectedItem.Text = ""
                    Else
                        'ddlNote.SelectedItem.Text = readNotes.GetValue(1)
                        ddlNote.SelectedItem.Selected = False
                        ddlNote.Items.FindByText(readNotes.GetValue(1)).Selected = True
                    End If
                    'Branch
                    If IsDBNull(readNotes.GetValue(2)) Then
                        ddBranchBox.Visible = False
                        ddBranchBox.SelectedItem.Text = ""
                    Else
                        ddBranchBox.SelectedItem.Text = readNotes.GetValue(2)
                    End If
                    'Account
                    If IsDBNull(readNotes.GetValue(3)) Then
                        txtAccountBox.Visible = False
                        txtAccountBox.Text = ""
                    Else
                        txtAccountBox.Text = readNotes.GetValue(3)
                    End If
                    'Type
                    If IsDBNull(readNotes.GetValue(4)) Then
                        ddTypeBox.Visible = False
                        ddTypeBox.SelectedItem.Text = ""
                    Else
                        ddTypeBox.SelectedItem.Text = readNotes.GetValue(4)
                    End If
                    'Sub
                    If IsDBNull(readNotes.GetValue(5)) Then
                        txtSubBox.Visible = False
                        txtSubBox.Text = ""
                    Else
                        txtSubBox.Text = readNotes.GetValue(5)
                    End If
                    conn.Close()
                    i += 1
                    cmdNote.Parameters.Clear()
                Next
                ButtonSubmit.Enabled = False
                ButtonSave.Enabled = False
                ButtonSaveTop.Enabled = False
            End If
            i = 0
            'cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            'cmdNote.Parameters.Clear()
            objSubmit = False
            dateStr = ""
            cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt(0)
            cmdNote.Parameters.Clear()
            objId.Clear()
        Next

        If objSubmit = True Then
            Return objSubmit
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        LblErr.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.DarkRed
        LblErr.Text = "CheckForSubmit - " & ex.Message
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Edit: I should also note that when I step through the code I see that the dropdowns do in fact have values, yet nothing is being displayed for them on the gridview, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer

I would compare drop down lists "note" and "note1"

e.g. note works but note1 doesn't.

The difference I can see between the 2 is that note has an empty list item. Try adding an empty list item to note 1.

Failing that, copy the working code from note and gradually replace it with the values from Note1, checking if/when it fails.

Comment: The dates look the same throughout all of the results, they're formatted the same way as what's in the database.

Comment: So the first one that works - is that "Note1" (where the list items are hardcoded manually through the asp code, but the other ones are populated through connections and SQLCommands - in that case, maybe there is an issue connecting or accessing the data in the database?

Comment: The first one that displays values is "Note", "Note1" is one of the ones that's having a problem and like you say is hard coded.

Comment: Adding a value to Note still made it work fine, removing the blank values from the other 3 yielded no success either. This problem is making me pull my hair out I have no idea what could be causing such a problem

Comment: Replacing the code of note with note1 did nothing as well, note still works without an issue

Comment: What about the selectindexchanged events - are those identical in note and note1?

Comment: I should also note the text values in the account and sub textboxes are coming back fine from the database and their code for retrieving values looks the same as the code for the dropdowns.

Comment: Did you check the selectedindexchange events? I suspect some event is getting in the way.

Comment: Nope they're very different form each other, the only thing going on in the selectedindexchanged for Note1 is 2 commented out lines of code, the selectedindexchanged for Note I will post.

Comment: Seems like we could be onto something there

Comment: Perhaps? But there is nothing at all in the selectedindexchanged of "Note1" (for the record stackoverflow won't let me post the code I have for Note sadly since it exceed the character limit) :(. Note's selectedindexchange has a lot going on because of the autopostback, the autopostback on the other 3 dropdowns was something i'd added in because i'd read something about that working for other people.

Comment: If you commented the selectedindexchanged code of Note, does that remove the dropdownlist values? If it does, then theres the need to have similar code in your note1 selectedindexchanged event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60209/discussion-between-ryan-j-and-robert-anderson).